# MongoDB using UTCDateTime in $gte doesn't work

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query

I'm writing a query to search for users created at specific date e.g.

```
$date = '2018-05-02 15:46:41.000Z';
User::raw(function ($col) use($date) { 
   return $col->aggregate([
        ['$match' =>
            'created_at' => ['$gte' => new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime($date))]
        ]
    ]);
});
```

Given an sample data like

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ae9dd61ef7a5754f159c656"),
  "name" : "Effie Larkin",
  "created_at" : ISODate("2018-05-02 15:46:41.000Z"),
}...
```

Expected result should be

```
{
  "users" : [
        "_id" : {"$oid": "5ae9dd61ef7a5754f159c656"},
        "name" "Effie Larkin",
        "created_at" : "2018-05-02 15:46:41"
   ]
}...
```

But I get an empty json array `[]`. I think the problem is in UTCDateTime function but I don't how to pass dateTime to it. I want to pass a time interval like 1 week ago or yesterday etc...  if anyone can help me will be much appreciated, thanks

Update, the example below fixed it

```
$date = '2018-05-02';
User::raw(function ($col) use($date) { 
   return $col->aggregate([
        ['$match' =>
            'created_at' => ['$gte' => new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime($date)*1000)]
        ]
    ]);
});
```

Comment: What you are claiming you have as a document in MongoDB is incorrect as the value showing in `ISODate()` is invalid. It should be `2018-05-02T15:46:41.000Z`, which makes it look like you're editing content from what it really is rather than simply copy/paste of what your actual document is. The most likely reason is because it's not actually the BSON Date you want to tell us it is, and therefore the query fails.  Also your output shows `$oid` for `ObjectId` which is correct, but the date would be showing `$date` for the same reason. It is not, so you likely really have a string.

Comment: Thanks for your help Neil, I figured it out. Yes you are right, the above example was written on top of my head and it wasn't what i was worried about. The query returning [ ] was because the created_at field has extra square brackets which wasn't needed. I will update my question so it reflect to what i originally intended